# preferred way of JSON file frequent up gradation using plain JS

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am making a extension for Google Chrome where i have to store JSON file. Now my extension need to upgrade the JSON file frequently.
Is there any way to upgrade the JSON file using **plain java script** without the "reading->editing->writing" cycle that means i can just **push the update** in the file directly.
Yup,i can do that writing some cutting edge code , i just want to know if there is a **built- in** way .
I am new in javacript realm. So providing resources while answering will be a great help.
And i prefer a solution in **plain JS** not in any frameworks.
Feel free to share any other **better approach** to do that.

UPDATED with example :
Lets assume there is a json file which have following value:

```
{"name" : "X"}
```

Now , i want to update "name"= "Y" directly into the file so it pushes the update to the json file.

```
{"name" : "Y"}
```

And also i may need to add a new node like "age":"20" and i would like it to push the update in the json file which will look like :

```
{"name" : "Y" , "age": "20"}
```

I am newbie in JS so maybe i failed to explain it precisely . I tried my best.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, can you provide some example as to what you want?

Comment: @Thrustmaster i have updated my question with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most newer versions of browsers support a filesystem API.

Take a look at this:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

There's also a library that implements the W3C `saveAs()` candidate (though I think this has been dropped from the spec these days).

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js